# How to require external libraries in google closure library?

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-library

I have a google closure component that uses an external library (socket.io.js)
Is it possible to require external libraries using something like goog.require and goog.addDependency
For example, something like this:

deps.js:

```
goog.addDependency('path/to/MyComponent.js', ['MyComponent'], ['goog.events', 'https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js']);
```

MyComponent.js:

```
goog.provide('MyComponent');
goog.require('goog.events');
// I want something like goog.require('https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js');
MyComponent = function() {
    var socket = io('http://localhost');
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding [externs](https://github.com/horaklukas/socket.io-externs) for socket.io

```
:externs ["externs/socket.io-externs.js"]
```

More info:

http://swannodette.github.io/2014/03/14/externs-got-you-down/
http://lukevanderhart.com/2011/09/30/using-javascript-and-clojurescript.html
https://blog.8thlight.com/taryn-sauer/2014/07/31/clojurescript-faux-pas.html

Answer (score 0):

socket.io.js is incompatible with google closure compiler, so you can't do it unless you adapt socket.io.js to work with google closure, some people did this for jquery for example but it's clearly not a viable solution and you have to do it for every new version blablala...nightmare 
Your best bet is to use --externs which tells closure compiler this is an external library and therefore all the code that comes from this library will not be renamed and will stay "valid" after compilation

https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#howto-app